# How can I explode a Hive map into a denormalized ("long") format?

Tags: hiveql

I want to take a bunch of user features (say, country, language, signup date, ...) and produce them in Hive in a denormalized 'long' format, i.e. rows of the form (userid, feature name, feature value), where feature name is something like "country" and feature value is something like "US".

I am using Hive 0.13.

The examples below all have one feature (country) for simplicity, but if I can get one to work, I'll add more.

Query #1:

```
select explode(map('country', get_json(json, 'country')))
from users
```

This works, with two columns of results (key, value) where the results look like

```
country  US
country  CA
...
```

Query #2:

```
select id, explode(map('country', get_json(json, 'country')))
from users
```

This fails with

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported
outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions
```

Query #3:

```
select key, value
from users
lateral view explode(map('country', get_json(json, 'country')))
```

This fails with

```
FAILED: ParseException line 3:63 cannot recognize input
near '' '' '' in table alias
```

Query #4:

```
select key, value
from users
lateral view explode(map('country', get_json(json, 'country'))) as (key, value)
```

This fails with

```
FAILED: ParseException line 3:67 missing EOF at '(' near 'as'
```

Is there a version of this that works?

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work.

```
select id, key, value
from users
lateral view explode(map('country', get_json(json, 'country'))) feature_row
```